# How to Send notification to mobile devices from localhost wamp server using wifi connection?

Tags: php, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I want to send notification to all mobile devices that are connected to the same WIFI point, the laptop is connected. Is it possible in php to detect the mobile devices connected to the WIFI and send notification as well as share the android apk package to all those connected android mobile device.

How to establish a communication between computer and android mobile device using wifi? And one important thing WIFI is only for local network environment [No Internet Connection Available]. How to achieve this using php? 
**Note:** Application is not already installed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to send a notification, your app should already be installed in the device. If you are looking for the same, go through this link [how to send a GCM notification](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). And then if you want to share any files, you could just send a link via GCM and download it in the mobile. It's not clear in your question if your app is already installed in the devices or you want to send the same apk without any app in the mobile.

Comment: Application is not already installed. Need to send notification along with APK to install the application.

Comment: It's impossible. How would android phone know how to receive your notification without anything installed in the phone?

Comment: okay. Please tell me, how to send notification if application is already installed. There is no internet connection, it should be done via WIFI connection.

Comment: Without internet connection, you can download apk from local url(like 192.168.1.x) but you can't send a GCM notification to mobile.